# Regression model for matched retrospective cohort study with continuous response variable

Tags: regression, logistic

I have a retrospective cohort study with matching (1:3) done. The response variable is charity care which is a continuous variable and the primary independent variable is hospital ranking which is a binary variable. Most statistical books suggest conditional logistic regression model to account for matching when the response variable is binary. However, given that I have a continuous response variable and matching was done, I'm having challenges getting a suitable regression model that accounts for matching. I can't convert the response variable to a binary variable (e.g. using the median) as it would have little or no practical meaning. I thought of converting it to tertiles; however, SAS (which I use) does not currently support conditional logistic regression with polytomous response variable. I will greatly appreciate suggestions on how to address this challenge. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you categorizing your response variable at all?

Comment: I do not intend to categorize the response variable. However, because matching was done, I am finding it difficult finding a regression model that accounts for the matching. From my understanding, conditional logistic regression is usually utilized when matching is done. But my response variable is not categorical; hence the challenge.

Comment: But logistic regression demands a categorical DV. The matching is separate from the analysis choice. Googling "linear regression matching" will find some resources)